# How do I use javascript to render blue gradient color

Tags: javascript, colors, background, gradient

I need to display text on a blue gradient color background within a table. How could I render this using Javascript?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS if you know that your visitors browsers support this feature:
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/11/css-gradients-firefox-36/

Another link worth visiting is this page that has a CSS generator that allows you to create the style interactively:
http://gradients.glrzad.com/

Here's the CSS for a blue gradient:

```
-webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.18, rgb(20,169,250)),
    color-stop(0.67, rgb(43,61,255)),
    color-stop(0.86, rgb(36,54,171))
)
-moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(20,169,250) 18%,
    rgb(43,61,255) 67%,
    rgb(36,54,171) 86%
)
```

Comment: hello,
I have another question.  My current code is like this which I apply a static color such as document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";. How do I apply this -webkit-gradient() style into this function?

function clickedElement(){
document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
}


Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: To your question, the style should be defined in a CSS class, say "banner", and then you'll be able to add that class to the elements you want by using document.getElementById("box1").className += " banner"; See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by css and background image with gradient.
use `background` css property.